# How to alias fields defined in Pivot SQL Server without getting duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to figure out how to rename my pivoted columns. IE 201601 to January, 201602 to February and etc.

The rest of the code is fine.

When I add the alias to the select statement, it creates another column with the month name but, leaves the original so I end up with 201601, 201602, etc followed by columns January, February, March, etc.

```
SELECT *, 

[201601] as January,  
[201602] as February,   
[201603] as March,   
[201604] as April,   
[201605] as May,   
[201606] as June, 
[201607] as July,     
[201608] as August,       
[201609] as September,    
[201610] as October,       
[201611] as November,   
[201612] as December


FROM (
SELECT  c.BLDGID AS 'BLDGID', 
        c.LEASID AS 'LEASID', 
        l.OCCPNAME AS 'OCCPNAME', 
        l.SUITID AS 'SUITID', 
        c.INCCAT AS 'INCCAT', 
        c.SRCCODE AS 'SRCCODE', 
        c.TRANAMT AS 'TRANAMT',
        c.PERIOD as 'PERIOD'
FROM SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS l
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG c
    ON l.BLDGID = c.BLDGID AND l.LEASID = c.LEASID
WHERE  c.BLDGID  ='85000' 
    AND c.INCCAT  ='RNT'  
    AND c.SRCCODE NOT LIKE 'CR'
    AND c.SRCCODE NOT LIKE 'PR'
    AND DESCRPTN NOT LIKE 'SECURITY APPLIED'


    AND c.PERIOD > '201512'
) as t
PIVOT (
SUM(TRANAMT) 
FOR PERIOD IN ([201601],[201602],[201603],[201604],[201605],[201606],[201607],[201608],[201609],[201610],[201611],[201612]) 




) revenueperspace
```

Comment: Have you tried `select . . ., [201601] as January, . . . ` ?

Comment: Yes, it creates a column named January but, leaves the column named 201601

Comment: Simple - follow the sound practice of *not using * for your columns*. This is desirable for several reasons, not least the one given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting both columns because you are using `SELECT *` in the first line. You should use this instead:

```
SELECT BLDGID, LEASID, OCCPNAME, SUITID, INCCAT, SRCCODE,
    [201601] as January,  
    [201602] as February,   
    [201603] as March,   
    [201604] as April,   
    [201605] as May,   
    [201606] as June, 
    [201607] as July,     
    [201608] as August,       
    [201609] as September,    
    [201610] as October,       
    [201611] as November,   
    [201612] as December
```

But of course, what will happen next year? You will have to keep updating the query. With this, you can avoid that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT  c.BLDGID AS 'BLDGID', 
        c.LEASID AS 'LEASID', 
        l.OCCPNAME AS 'OCCPNAME', 
        l.SUITID AS 'SUITID', 
        c.INCCAT AS 'INCCAT', 
        c.SRCCODE AS 'SRCCODE', 
        c.TRANAMT AS 'TRANAMT', 
        DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, CAST(SUBSTRING(c.PERIOD, 5, 2) AS INT), -1)) AS 'MONTH'
FROM SQLDATA.dbo.LEAS l
INNER JOIN SQLDATA.dbo.CMLEDG c
    ON l.BLDGID = c.BLDGID AND l.LEASID = c.LEASID
WHERE  c.BLDGID &SPARM01
    AND c.INCCAT &SPARM02 
    AND c.SRCCODE NOT LIKE 'CR'
    AND c.SRCCODE NOT LIKE 'PR'
    AND DESCRPTN NOT LIKE 'SECURITY APPLIED'
    AND c.PERIOD > '201512'
) as t
PIVOT (
SUM(TRANAMT) 
FOR MONTH IN ('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December') 

) revenueperspace
```

The first change is convert your period to month name, and I do that in the subquery (*201606 -> 'June', for example*), so the pivot table doesn't even know that `yyyymm` format exists. Then just use the months you want in the list used for the pivot table and you are done.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I will review these on Monday. I know the first one works after you TRANAMT is removed as it's part of the Pivot but, I received other errors on the second one. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: You are right about that field, it's the aggregated one so I removed it from the SELECT. As I modified your query without being able to test it, it may have some issues. I didn't have the time to guess and replicate your table structure for this. :) I suggest you try to make the second one work. Please share the errors or how you solved it so I can fix it.